# Not able to load login page - Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have set up spring mvc project and now want to implement Spring-Security in it .
I earlier had Spring 3.2.8 version of jars , so i included Spring-security jars of same version 3.2.8.

**security-context.xml**

```
 <http authentication-manager-ref="custom" auto-config="true"
        use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="pages/login/login.jsp" access="permitAll"/> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll"/>
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login/login.jsp" access="permitAll"/> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/image/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/include/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/javascript/**" access="permitAll" />


        <intercept-url pattern="/userAuthentication.htm/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access= "isAuthenticated()"/>

        <form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/userAuthentication.htm?method=login"
            always-use-default-target="false" password-parameter="j_password"
            username-parameter="j_username"
            authentication-failure-url="/pages/errorPage/unauthorizedAccess.jsp?login_error=1" />
        </http>

        <authentication-manager id="custom"
        alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>


        </beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sanitizerFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.mobicule.util.SanitizerFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<% response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+ "/login"); %>
```

I also have /login Request Mapping in one of my Controllers , which returns new ModelAndView("login/login")
Still i get **Web Page not Found - took too long to respond**

I am confused as what configurations are missing ??,
It is not able to find my login.jsp page which is under directory
**Web-Content/pages/login/login.jsp**

Also i am using Tomcat 6 as this is the requirement of my project.

Comment: did you set listener-class and context-param in web.xml? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/helloworld-xml.html

Comment: @MehranMastcheshmi yes i have set listener class as ContextLoaderListener and context-param  <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/spring-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>